# SUDO asks for "Encryption passphrase" on new setup with LUKS

Tags: ubuntu, security, encryption, sudo, luks

SUDO keeps asking for `Encryption passphrase` on my latest setup. I'm not sure what encryption the passphrase is for, except that I suspect that it is related to LUKS encryption. Also I noted it doesn't matter which passphrase I enter

The output I get is for instance the following:

```
rohdef@rohdef-januar ~/g/januar-k8s (main)> sudo true
[sudo] password for rohdef: 
Encryption passphrase:
```

If relevant the setup I used for the disk encryption is [How to Dual-Boot Ubuntu 20.04 (or 22.04) and Windows 10 with Encryption](https://www.mikekasberg.com/blog/2020/04/08/dual-boot-ubuntu-and-windows-with-encryption.html) with the modifications that I resized an existing Windows rather than installing it after and that I did not re-enable bitlocker.

What is the `Encryption passphrase` it asks for, and how do I disable it?

Comment: Are you sure it's `sudo` that's asking? Try `sudo true` ("do nothing successfully as root")

Comment: @gronostaj I am, yes :) forgot to mention, but I did of course retry with multiple commands :) I updated the post above, since your way of reproducing is better than mine :) thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by random incident I discovered a detail in my syslog (not sure how I overlooked that earlier)

The issue is with the `pam_ecryptfs` module that tries to automount. This can simply be fixed by going though the pam configurations in `/etc/pam.d` and disabling the module when it's require (e.g. by commenting it out). On my system it is referenced in `common-auth`

The lines in syslog that revealed the underlying issue are:

```
2023-04-17T10:24:29.637814+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: pam_ecryptfs: Passphrase file wrapped
2023-04-17T10:24:29.638061+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: Passphrase size is invalid; [1] to [64] is the valid range
2023-04-17T10:24:29.638165+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: Error generating passphrase signature; rc = [-22]
2023-04-17T10:24:29.638255+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: Error attempting to unwrap passphrase from file [/home/rohdef/.ecryptfs/wrapped-passphrase]; rc = [-22]
2023-04-17T10:24:29.638350+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: pam_ecryptfs: Error adding passphrase key token to user session keyring; rc = [-5]
2023-04-17T10:24:29.641576+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: pam_intune(sudo-i:session): Processing user session startup
2023-04-17T10:24:29.641733+02:00 rohdef-januar sudo: pam_intune(sudo-i:session): Processed Intune policy for rohdef
```